# Cannot POST /.php file when submitting form for email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I'm trying to get a HTML from to work together with PHP in order to make a form for sending a mail, but after submitting the form, PHP file is saying

```
Cannot POST /quotation.php
```

Here is my HTML code

```
  <div id="quotation" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
     <h3>Request Quotation</h3>
     <p>Please fill out this information and we will contact you as soon as possilble.</p>
       <form method="post" name="" action="quotation.php">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="large-6 columns">
             <label>Name
               <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
             </label>
           </div>
           <div class="large-6 columns">
             <label>Lastname
               <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" />
             </label>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="large-6 columns">
             <label>Company name
               <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Your company">
             </label>
           </div>
           <div class="large-6 columns">
             <label>E-mail
               <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail">
             </label>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="large-12 columns">
             <label>Additional details
               <textarea name="message" placeholder="Additional details here"></textarea>
             </label>
           </div>
         </div>
         <input class="button radius" type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
       </form>
     </div>
```

And this is the PHP that runs the form

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email_from = $visitor_email;//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name, $lastname.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "email@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
alert("yo");
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: index.html');
?>
```

I added alert and echo for submit button, but none of them appears so looks like PHP is not even running.
It would be great if someone could guide me trough this problem or point out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you running this from your own computer or a hosted service?

Comment: alert is not a native PHP function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm running this on a localhost server. Will try to upload it on the web and see what happens.

Comment: If PHP isn't installed on your machine then it won't work, as will `mail()`. Try your code on a live server/hosted service and am next to certain it will work. Also, as stated above, `alert()` is not a native PHP function, you'll need to wrap in in JS syntax, or just remove it altogether. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Technically, this should work; I don't see anything wrong with your code, besides the `alert()`

Comment: Wait, I kind of take that back (*about not containing errors in your code*); you're outputting before header with the echo. Either remove the echo, or remove the `header("Location...` as well as the `alert`. That alone will throw a `headers already sent...` error message.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, you were right about trying the code live. I still received an error for that `alert` but mail was sent successfully.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it's been resolved, *cheers*

Comment: If you absolutely want an `alert`, do `echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';` but you'll need to get rid of the `header("Location...` if you're going to use it <=(the alert).